# template-template-parameter and concepts

Tags: c++, c++-concepts, template-templates

Is it possible to write concepts for template-template parameter?

In

```
template<template<typename> typename T> struct A {};
```

I want to check if a specific instantiation of  `T` satisfies a concept.

Example:

```
template<typename F>
concept bool HasF = requires(F) {
    F::f();
};

template<typename T>
struct Test1 {
    static void f() {}
};

template<typename T>
struct Test2 {
};

template<template<typename> typename T> 
//requires HasF<T<B>> // not possible
struct A {
    struct B {
    };    
};


using x1 = A<Test1>;
using x2 = A<Test2>; // should fail
```

In the above example I can't use `B` because it isn't declared at the point of use.

Comment: I guess `template<template<typename> typename T> requires a_concept<T<specific_type>> struct A {}`?

Comment: Ok. But what if `specific_type` is only known inside `A`. So, we can't write the requires-clause in the preamble.

Comment: can you give a concrete example?

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: you example doesn't really support your origin question... `Test1` don't have any specific instantiation that don't satisfy `HasF`, and `template-template` really not point here (same problem for simply check `HasF<B>`). To summarize, it's a totally different question.

Comment: Edited once more.

Comment: like I just said, you ask a totally different question, would you mind open a new question with [this example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MjIWeja1JfWxao7u)? then rollback or just delete this question.

Comment: well, if `A<T>` does not even valid, how can you check `T<A<T>::B>`?

Answer (score 0):

```
template<template<typename> typename T> requires a_concept<T<specific_type>> 
struct A {}
```